# Module assigned in joomla page does not appear

Tags: html, joomla, joomla-module

I created a costume HTML module with one plugin tag inserted in there to display on a page on Joomla. 
I assigned the module to the page. It is enabled and the position is chosen, but once I load the page the module is not there. Am I doing something wrong?

The page that I assigned the module to is a Hidden page in the menu.

The plugin in suppose to display a MP3 player

http://youth-panel.com/nava-nama/preaching?id=1403

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a plugin in a module, you need to enable content preparation.
Edit your module, go to the 'options' tab and select 'Prepare Content' - Yes